# How insert console.log inside an arrow function with at least 2 lines

Tags: console.log, arrow-functions

I´m having some issues trying to include a console.log statemente inside a arrow function:

```
tap((selectedSite: Site) => console.log(selectedSite), this.userForm.controls.sites.setValue(...selectedSite.id))
```

Comment: enclose your method definition inside curly braces like tap((selectedSite) => { console.log(selectedSite), this.userForm.controls.sites.setValue(...selectedSite.id)})

Comment: Yes thanks, but I meant without using curly braces